LC cross coupled oscillator gain
I'm having a hard time understanding how a cross coupled LC oscillator eventually reaches a loop gain of 1 and allows the output to stabilise at a certain value.

From the reading I've done, stabilisation seems to occur due to "nonlinear MOSFET characteristics" or when losses in the LC tank are equal to losses in the MOSFET. Sadly neither of those answers are intuitively correct to me and I suspect I've misunderstood.
So, if stabilisation occurs due to "nonlinear MOSFET characteristics", what are these nonlinear behaviours? One topic that seems to be mentioned often in this regard is gain compression. If I understand that correctly, this occurs at large values of Vgs where the drain current plateaus. In small signal analysis, this would be equivalent to gm either plateauing or decreasing for increasing Vgs. However, if I look at the MOSFET square law equations, gm increases linearly with Vgs and therefore exhibits no compression. So either my MOSFET model is too basic to predict the finite loop gain correctly, or I'm misunderstanding the limiting mechanism (likely).
The other aspect that I've often read that alludes to the reason for the stabilisation is when the losses in the MOSFET equals the energy stored in the LC tank and therefore the output voltage no longer increases. If this is correct, what characteristics of the MOSFET is it that grows at larger output values and leads to an equilibrium state? I was wondering if this is perhaps related to channel length modulation as I believe that the drain current through the MOSFET would increase with increasing Vds and therefore limit the amount of energy that could be stored in the LC tank?
Really my question comes down to asking for an explanation of what's limiting the loop gain here and allowing the circuit to function as an oscillator. Related to this, are the MOSFET square law equations accurate enough models to predict a stable oscillation output value?

Have you tried using a simulator to see what p-p voltage is the limit.

I've tried that using my circuit simulator. It seems to top it at around 10.5V and swings to about -0.4V at the minimum. I also tired using the level 1 and level 3 models which produced broadly comparable results. I think level 1 is the square law equations so it seems like they are capable of predicting the gain stabilisation.

That's the maximum you can ever get out of this circuit when run from 5 volts so, it's soft clipping (as an experienced EE would expect).
